# Color code worksheet tab

Tags: office-js

I'm working on an Excel add-in using the JavaScript APIs to build add-ins in Excel Office 365. [ Mac ] Office js version - 1.3

I want to color code the worksheet tab. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab color is part of Excel 1.7, which is not yet released on MacBook (no ETA). It is available in Beta stage in Windows and Excel online now. You can look at the API [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/ExcelJs_OpenSpec/reference/excel/worksheet.md). Will update this thread when it becomes available on MAC.